# GADInterstitial splash dismiss with warning

Tags: ios, admob

I want to add GADInterstitial to my iOS game, so everytime the app become active I want to present interestitial. In my AppDelegate.m, in method applicationDidBecomeActive: i call my method

```
-(void)splashInterstitial{
interestitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
interestitial.adUnitID = ADMOB_ID;
interestitial.delegate = self;
[interestitial loadAndDisplayRequest:[self createRequest] usingWindow:self.window   initialImage:nil];
```

}

But everytime i close the ad i get warning:

```
attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self = <GADInterstitialAppController: 0x5d3ed0> modalViewController = <GADWebAppViewController: 0x5d1ca0>
```

Does anyone got that warning?

Comment: Same problem. Has somebody fixed this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Just always check will your initialization and visualization of banner after

> viewDidAppear

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    hasLoaded = YES;
    [self splashInterstitial];
}
```